# pandas fill forward performance issue

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multi index (Date, InputTime) and this dataframe may contain some NA values in the columns (Value, Id). I want to fill forward value but by Date only and I don't find anyway to do this a in a very efficient way.

Here is the type of dataframe I have :

[image: Dataframe example]

And here is the result I want :

[image: Dataframe properly fill forward by date only]

So to properly fillback by date I can use groupby(level=0) function. The groupby is fast but the fill function apply on the dataframe group by date is really too slow.

Here is the code I use to compare simple fill forward (which doesn't give the expected result but is run very quickly) and expected fill forward by date (which give expected result but is really too slow).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Show pandas & numpy versions
print('pandas '+pd.__version__)
print('numpy '+np.__version__)

# Build a big list of (Date,InputTime,Value,Id)
listdata = []
d = dt.datetime(2001,10,6,5)
for i in range(0,100000):
    listdata.append((d.date(), d, 2*i if i%3==1 else np.NaN, i if i%3==1 else np.NaN))
    d = d + dt.timedelta(hours=8)

# Create the dataframe with Date and InputTime as index
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(listdata, index=['Date','InputTime'], columns=['Date', 'InputTime', 'Value', 'Id'])

# Simple Fill forward on index
start = dt.datetime.now()
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].ffill()
end = dt.datetime.now()
print "Time to fill forward on index = " + str((end-start).total_seconds()) + " s"

# Fill forward on Date (first level of index)
start = dt.datetime.now()
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].groupby(level=0).ffill()
end = dt.datetime.now()
print "Time to fill forward on Date only = " + str((end-start).total_seconds()) + " s"
```

[image: Results]

Could somebody explain me why this code is so slow or help me to find an efficient way to fill forward by date on big dataframes?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to iterate over the cols? If you didn't set the index to those cols but just did this: `df.groupby(['Date','InputTime']).fillna()` won't this give you what you want?

Answer (score 5):

github/jreback: this is a dupe of #7895. .ffill is not implemented in cython on a groupby operation (though it certainly could be), and instead calls python space on each group.
here's an easy way to do this.
url:https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11296

### according to jreback's answer, when you do a groupby ffill() is not optimized, but cumsum() is. try this:

```
df = df.sort_index()
df.ffill() * (1 - df.isnull().astype(int)).groupby(level=0).cumsum().applymap(lambda x: None if x == 0 else 1)
```

utility function: (credit to @Phun)

```py
def ffill_se(df: pd.DataFrame, group_cols: List[str]):
    df['GROUP'] = df.groupby(group_cols).ngroup()
    df.set_index(['GROUP'], inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    df = df.ffill() * (1 - df.isnull().astype(int)).groupby(level=0).cumsum().applymap(lambda x: None if x == 0 else 1)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return df
```

Comment: boy, this answer should be way more popular! what an speedup! THANKS!

A convinient function:
```
def ffill_se(df, group_cols):

    df['GROUP'] = df.groupby(group_cols).ngroup()
    df.set_index(['GROUP'], inplace=True)
    
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    df = df.ffill() * (1 - df.isnull().astype(int)).groupby(level=0).cumsum().applymap(lambda x: None if x == 0 else 1)

    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return df
```

Comment: This works great, but I cannot get it to keep the datetime index of my dataframe. Any ideas how to change this to allow for that?