# forward fill (ffill) based on group and previous row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (400,000+ rows), that looks like this:

```
data = np.array([
          [1949, '01/01/2018', np.nan, 17,     '30/11/2017'],
          [1949, '01/01/2018', np.nan, 19,      np.nan],
          [1811, '01/01/2018',     16, np.nan, '31/11/2017'],
          [1949, '01/01/2018',     15, 21,     '01/12/2017'],
          [1949, '01/01/2018', np.nan, 20,      np.nan],
          [3212, '01/01/2018',     21, 17,     '31/11/2017']
         ])
columns = ['id', 'ReceivedDate', 'PropertyType', 'MeterType', 'VisitDate']
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Resultant df:

```
     id     ReceivedDate    PropertyType    MeterType   VisitDate
0   1949    01/01/2018       NaN              17       30/11/2017
1   1949    01/01/2018       NaN              19       NaN
2   1811    01/01/2018       16              NaN       31/11/2017
3   1949    01/01/2018       15               21       01/12/2017
4   1949    01/01/2018       NaN              20       NaN
5   3212    01/01/2018       21               17       31/11/2017
```

I want to forward fill based on groupby (id & received date) - ONLY IF they come next in order in the index (i.e. only forward fill index positions 1 and 4).

I am thinking to have a column that says if it should be ffilled or not based on the criteria, but how can I check the row above?

(I plan on using a solution along the lines of this answer: [pandas fill forward performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019877/pandas-fill-forward-performance-issue)

`df.isnull().astype(int)).groupby(level=0).cumsum().applymap(lambda x: None if x == 0 else 1)`

as `x = df.groupby(['id','ReceivedDate']).ffill()` is very slow.)

Desired df:

```
     id     ReceivedDate    PropertyType    MeterType   VisitDate
0   1949    01/01/2018       NaN              17       30/11/2017
1   1949    01/01/2018       NaN              19       30/11/2017
2   1811    01/01/2018       16              NaN       31/11/2017
3   1949    01/01/2018       15               21       01/12/2017
4   1949    01/01/2018       15               20       01/12/2017
5   3212    01/01/2018       21               17       31/11/2017
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['id', 'ReceivedDate']).ffill(limit=1)`?

Comment: sometimes I could have 2 rows in a row, and I am trying to avoid `df.groupby.ffill` as it takes ~1 second per 1000 rows (too slow).

Comment: But since you're limiting the number of forward fills, it could become faster?

Comment: Unfortunately not enough, just tested on 10,000 rows. `ffill()` = 11.2sec, `ffill(limit=1)` = 11.1 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `groupby` and `ffill` with `limit=1`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'ReceivedDate']).ffill(limit=1)

     id ReceivedDate PropertyType MeterType   VisitDate
0  1949   01/01/2018          NaN        17  30/11/2017
1  1949   01/01/2018          NaN        19  30/11/2017
2  1811   01/01/2018           16        18  31/11/2017
3  1949   01/01/2018           15        21  01/12/2017
4  1949   01/01/2018           15        20  01/12/2017
5  3212   01/01/2018           21        17  31/11/2017
```

---

### `groupby` with `mask`ing and `shift`

Try filling NaNs with `groupby`, `mask`, and `shift` -

```
i = df[['id', 'ReceivedDate']]
j = i.ne(i.shift().values).any(1).cumsum()
```

```
df.mask(df.isnull().astype(int).groupby(j).cumsum().eq(1), df.groupby(j).shift())
```

Or,

```
df.where(df.isnull().astype(int).groupby(j).cumsum().ne(1), df.groupby(j).shift())
```

```
     id ReceivedDate PropertyType MeterType   VisitDate
0  1949   01/01/2018          NaN        17  30/11/2017
1  1949   01/01/2018          NaN        19  30/11/2017
2  1811   01/01/2018           16        18  31/11/2017
3  1949   01/01/2018           15        21  01/12/2017
4  1949   01/01/2018           15        20  01/12/2017
5  3212   01/01/2018           21        17  31/11/2017
```

Comment: It forward fills even on row 2, where there is a nan (which I don't want) - i'll update the question to show this "edge case"

Comment: @AH Added an explanation for you. I think this should work, but I'm not 100% certain on performance.

Comment: So the code does not check if the previous row has the same `id` and `ReceivedDate`

Comment: I did, it gave me some ideas, (it didn't answer my question completely, but that's because I didn't ask my question well enough the first time - sorry about that). Thank you.

Comment: @AH So, is the answer wrong? Why doesn't it work, would you help me understand? I'd rather delete it if it wasn't useful. Also, timings wise, how useful is it?

Comment: @Coldspeed, timing wise, it's excellent. The problem is that the groupby did not consider the `receivedate` and the `id` (i.e. it will just ffill regardless of the `receivedate` - you can see this with the updated example I posted (theres an extra `nan` in row `2`). However, your explanation was very good. I will be using in my code shift/mask rather than ffill, so thanks. I will add an answer of what I did.

Comment: @AH My latest code sample takes this into consideration, however I'm not sure how fast _it_ is.

Comment: @coldspeed haha, awesome. your solution gives the same as mine. It does it in `686 ms ± 23.8 ms per loop`.
My solution does it in `257 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop`, but it gives the same result. Was looking for a sub-1 second answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AH I'm surprised that a solution involving apply/applymap can be faster than a completely non-loopy solution, but pandas surprises you every now and then! Feel free to add an answer with timings, I'd like to see your approach (and upvote, if possible).

Comment: @coldspeed, oh sorry, im not using applymap, im using a modified version of your shift result

Comment: @AH You optimised my answer? Nice! Feel free to edit my answer with your code, or add your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
cols_to_ffill = ['PropertyType', 'VisitDate']
i = df.copy()

newdata = pd.DataFrame(['placeholder'] )

while not newdata.index.empty:

    RowAboveid = i.id.shift()
    RowAboveRD = i.ReceivedDate.shift()
    rows_with_cols_to_ffill_all_empty = i.loc[:, cols_to_ffill].isnull().all(axis=1)
    rows_to_ffill = (i.ReceivedDate == RowAboveRD) & (i.id == RowAboveid) & (rows_with_cols_to_ffill_all_empty)
    rows_used_to_fill = i[rows_to_ffill].index-1

    newdata = i.loc[rows_used_to_fill, cols_to_ffill]
    newdata.index +=1
    i.loc[rows_to_ffill, cols_to_ffill] = newdata
```

Keeps looping until no more matches (i.e. all columns are forward filled.)